# Range of $a$ such that $w \leftarrow w-a x \langle w, x \rangle$ converges almost surely?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers

**Edit Sep 19** this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430790/7655) on Mathoverflow matches simulation results

Suppose $x_i$ come from 2-d standard Normal centered at 0. What is the range of $a$ for which the following iteration converges almost surely?

$$w_{i+1} = w_i-a x_i \langle w_i, x_i \rangle$$

Mean norm of $w$ diverges for $a>2/3$ but this is vacuous because variance also diverges. The answer is [somewhere](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/simple-simulation.nb) between 0.9 and 1.1.

How do I get a more accurate estimate?

[image]

**Here's a way to verify that $a=2$ converges for 1D, which doesn't generalize to 2D**

Note that our process defines the following recursion on $w^2$

$$\log w_{k+1}^2 = \log (1-\alpha x^2)^2 + \log w_k^2$$

Here we see that $\log w_{k+1}^2$ is a sum of $k$ independent random variables, tending towards $-\infty$ as $k$ grows whenever $E[\log (1-\alpha x^2)^2]<0$, from Central Limit Theorem.

Since $E[\log (1-\alpha x^2)^2]\approx 0$ for $\alpha \approx
2.42129$, this also forms the critical rate, and can be verified in simulations by looking at median value of trajectories for $\alpha$ slightly above, and slightly below critical

[image]

**Edit Aug 24**

Expectation in answer has a closed form solution in terms of exponential [integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E1), can be [obtained](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272584/217) in Mathematica. Plotting it for $d=2$ there are two critical points, for $a=0.121312$ and for $a=0.918611$

[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to rewrite your iterations as $w_{k+1} = w_k - a x_k\langle w_k, x_k\rangle$ to make it more clear to readers that the $x_k$'s are all iid standard normals rather than a single $x$ realized one time.

Answer (score 6):

Your iterations can be rewritten as $w_n \leftarrow w_{n-1} - axx^\top w$, or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
w_n \leftarrow (I - axx^\top)w_{n-1}
\end{equation*}
and so can be seen to be a form of [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration). Therefore, your iterations converge to the dominant eigenvector of $I - axx^\top$. It is straightforward to calculate that for $x = (x_1, x_2)$, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1 - ax_1^2 - ax_2^2$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(-x_2/x_1, 1)$ and $(x_1/x_2, 1)$ respectively.

If $\lambda_1 = 1$ is the dominant eigenvalue, then your iterations will converge, since $w_n \rightarrow c\cdot(-x_2/x_1, 1)$ for some finite constant c (that depends on the initial $w_0$). Next, note that $\lambda_2 \leq 1$, and so is the dominant eigenvalue if and only if $\lambda_2 < -1$. This happens iff $x_1^2 + x_2^2 > 2/a$, which occurs with probability $\Pr(\chi^2_2 > 2/a)$. But in this event, $|\lambda_2| > 1$, and so $|w_n| \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and your iterations diverge.

In summary, your iteration scheme diverges with probability $\Pr(\chi^2_2 > 2/a)$ for almost all initializations of $w_0$ (with the exception of $w_0 \in \operatorname{span}(\{(-x_2/x_1, 1)\})$, which of course happens with probability $0$).

---

Below is some Python 3 code that can help verify these findings. One can try various values of $a$ and find that the expected number of divergences is fairly close to the expected number from the chi-square distribution.

```py
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from scipy.stats import chi2
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

a = 0.9
num_diverged = 0
for i in range(1000):
    x = multivariate_normal.rvs([0, 0])

    w = 20 * multivariate_normal.rvs([0, 0]) # a random initialization for w

    for _ in range(1000):
        w = w - a * w.dot(x) * x
        #w = w/(w[0]**2 + w[1]**2)**0.5  # Uncomment to see normalized w's

    print()
    print("Final w:              ", w)
    if np.isnan(sum(w)) or abs(w[0]) > 100 or abs(w[1]) > 100:
        num_diverged += 1
    print("Normalized w:         ", w/np.linalg.norm(w))
    if 2 <= a * x[0]**2 + a* x[1]**2:
        x = np.array([x[0]/x[1], 1])
    else:
        x = np.array([-x[1]/x[0], 1])
    print("Expected normalized w:", x/np.linalg.norm(x))

print()
print("Number diverged:", num_diverged)
print("Expected diverged:", chi2.sf(2/a, 2)*1000)
```

Partial output:

```
Number diverged: 335
Expected diverged: 329.1929878079054
```

Comment: Running with a=0.9 actually makes all of my trajectories converge, I think you are solving slightly different problem here, adding "abs(w[0]) > 100 or abs(w[1]) > 100" makes the process non-Markov

Comment: A simpler case is to run with 1-d standard normal, you can show that a=2.421249521 is the cutoff rate, both theoretically and in simulation

Comment: I'm only using "abs(w[0]) > 100 or abs(w[1]) > 100" as a check to see that w has diverged. The iteration I'm running is simply "w = w - a * w.dot(x) * x" which is precisely what you asked about.

Comment: 100 as a cutoff modifies the problem. For instance, if you change it to 1.7E+308, then the number of "diverged" trajectories drops to 173 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OC9r1yi5g882FfJ54DNDl5-V3eOfrE_J#scrollTo=uJSXbrLwraRH . If you run at higher precision (like I did in Mathematica), the number drops further. I believe almost all trajectories eventually converge

Comment: Changing it to 1.7E+308 is far past the point at which you start running into floating point issues. The point is that with the probability $\Pr(\chi^2_2 > 2/a)$, the magnitude of $w_n$ increases by a factor of about $|1 - a|x|^2|$ each iteration, and so $|w_n|$ diverges and hence $w_n$.

Comment: Updated the post with 1D case, [running](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QvVRuCQDGkWwz4mjvZ6fBeaBqA_Q90eQ#scrollTo=G82yuJXguJpc) simulation at $a=2$, makes some trajectories diverge due to numerical issue, even though all trajectories converge almost surely in unlimited precision

Comment: What definition of convergence are you using? When I say converge, I mean that there exists $v$ such that $|w_n - v| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. In the case of the 1D Gaussian, $w_n = (1 - ax^2)^n w_0$, and so the sequence converges iff it converges to zero iff $|1 - ax^2| < 1$. Hence, under my definition of convergence, the $w_n$ sequence diverges when $1 - ax^2 < -1$ which happens with probability $\Pr(\chi^2_1 > 2/a)$.

Comment: I'm looking at "almost sure" convergence -- probability of of being $\epsilon$ away from 0 goes to zero as steps go to infinity. Your argument doesn't work because the process is not Markov -- moving away from 0 increases magnitude of future steps towards zero. However, it's markov on log-scale, so E[log(1-ax^2)]<0 implies a.s.. convergence

Comment: OK, I see the misunderstanding now -- in the code you reuse same value of $x$ for each step, whereas I use a different value for each step, edited the q for clarity

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$
This is a new answer for the updated question, where we have a sequence of Gaussians instead of a single $x$.

We have that $w_n = \left[\prod_{i=1}^n (I - ax_ix_i^\top)\right]w_0$, and want to examine the behavior as $n\rightarrow \infty$. We're going to use the trick that an infinite product converges to zero iff the product of squares converges to zero:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2 
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left(n\cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2\right) \\
&\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left(n\cdot \E\left[\log(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2\right]\right)
\end{align*}

Above, we use the matrix exponential and matrix logarithm. Using the spectral decomposition
\begin{equation*}
(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{i,2}/x_{i,1} & x_{i, 1}/x_{i,2} \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & (1-a||x_i||^2)^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{x_{1,i}x_{2,i}}{||x_i||^2} & \frac{x_{1,i}^2}{||x_i||^2} \\ \frac{x_{1,i}x_{2,i}}{||x_i||^2} & \frac{x_{2,i}^2}{||x_i||^2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
we can calculate that
\begin{equation*}
\E\left[\log(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2\right] = \begin{bmatrix}
\E\left[\frac{x_{1,i}^2}{||x_i||^2}\cdot\log(1-a||x_i||^2)^2\right] & 0 \\ 0 & \E\left[\frac{x_{2,i}^2}{||x_i||^2}\cdot\log(1-a||x_i||^2)^2\right]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Thus, we are concerned with when the following matrix has limit zero:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\begin{bmatrix}
\exp\left(\E\left[\frac{x_{1,i}^2}{||x_i||^2}\cdot\log(1-a||x_i||^2)^2\right]\right) & 0 \\ 0 & \exp\left(\E\left[\frac{x_{2,i}^2}{||x_i||^2}\cdot\log(1-a||x_i||^2)^2\right]\right)
\end{bmatrix}^n
\end{equation*}

and this of course happens iff it has norm less than 1. That is,
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{2\cdot \left[\exp\left(\E\left[\frac{x_{1,i}^2}{||x_i||^2}\cdot\log(1-a||x_i||^2)^2\right]\right)\right]^2} < 1
\end{equation*}

Some numerical integration suggests that the critical value is roughly $a \approx 0.92$.

Comment: Neat! Looks [like](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-largest-a.nb) the cut-off is 0.91861

Comment: 1) is there a name for the trick (on product of squares?) Product is not commutative, so this seems like a strong statement. 2) using numerical integration there [seems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272489/217) to be a second root at 0.121....this seems unphysical -- all positive values in vicinity of 0 should converge  3) in [simulations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-largest-a.nb), 0.93 seems to be convergent (while 0.94 diverges)

Comment: Here's one issue with this formulation -- for $a$ close to 0, the term on the left-hand side is close to $\sqrt{2}$ so it violates the norm condition. Meanwhile we can show that for any $a<0.6667, E[\|w\|^2]\rightarrow 0$

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i^2 = \exp(\sum_{i=1}^n \log(A_i^2)) = \exp(2\sum_{i=1}^n\log(A_i))$. Similarly, $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i = \exp(\sum_{i=1}^n \log(A_i))$ so both these products converge iff $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(A_i)$ converges. This of course depends on the existence of the matrix logarithm--which is a technicality did leave out of the answer. It is plausible that for small enough $a$, $(I−ax_ix_i^\top)^2$ is outside the radius of convergence with nonzero probability which leads to your observed discrepancies.

Comment: Actually, it's very well possible that I calculated the logarithm of $(I - ax_ix_i^\top)^2$ incorrectly; I'll check this out later.

Comment: Does it make sense to take matrix logarithm of rank-deficient matrix? All matrices in the product are rank-1